# How to skip empty records CSVFormat parser

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv

I am required in this set of code to parse a csv file given the URL. The problem is that some times, the file will have empty lines appended at the end of the file(I currently have no control on the file being parsed). The solution here is to ignore lines where all values are not provided when parsing the file

Here is some sample data:

```
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER13,HEADER4,HEADER5,HEADER6
1,tt,9/2/2019,12000,4116,2307306
2,tt1,9/2/2019,12000,4147,1137039
,,,,,,
,,,,,,
```

I have tried the following solution without success

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreEmptyLines(true).parse(new FileReader(url));
```

In this case,  the expected result would be to get the first two lines after the header and ignore the last two lines

Comment: Can you try to use CSVFormat.DEFAULT instead of CSVFormat.EXCEL and try ?

Comment: I'm guessing that by "empty lines" they actually mean empty lines, i.e. the "\r\n\r\n\r\n" sequence, not what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below code and check whether it works.

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreEmptyLines(true).withTrim().parse(new FileReader(url));
```

I have added a method `.withTrim()`.

If it still does not work, you can check each CSVRecord as null or not inside for loop.

Comment: I had thought of checking this in a loop but it would be inefficient. Especially for large data sets. Imagine iterating through 100k records to get only 100 records.